# How to measure through-output and latency in Flink when using a bounded Kafka data source？

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a Flink application and want to evaluate the performance of the app.

My plan is to use a bounded history dataset as the data source in the experiment, by measuring the total time cost, I can get the through-output value. And by querying the latency metric, I can get the latency condition.

However, when using Kafka as a data source, after consuming the specific amount of data, the app seems still **waiting** for other data to be consumed and don't turn to FINISHED state. I think during the waiting time, the through output value and the latency may get lower, which is not related to the application's performance.

In this condition, how can I get the precise time cost and the latency condition related to my bounded data set, and avoid the influence comes from the extra-waiting stage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `KafkaSource`, rather than `FlinkKafkaConsumer`, you can specify ending offsets by using `setBounded`, as in

```java
KafkaSource<String> source = KafkaSource
        .<String>builder()
        .setBootstrapServers(...)
        .setGroupId(...)
        .setTopics(...)
        .setDeserializer(...)
        .setStartingOffsets(OffsetsInitializer.earliest())
        .setBounded(OffsetsInitializer.latest())
        .build();

env.fromSource(source, watermarkStrategy, "name"));
```

That way a bounded job using Kafka as a source will cleanly come to an end.

If you need to accomplish the same thing with a `FlinkKafkaConsumer`, then implement a `DeserializationSchema` (or a `KafkaDeserializationSchema`) that at some point returns TRUE from `isEndOfStream`.

Comment: How can I ignore the time cost of job initialization when calculating the total time cost of a Flink job?